# Cannot insert an item that is already owned by another QTableWidget

Tags: c++, qt, qtablewidget, qtablewidgetitem

I'm having issues with QTableWidgetTable, after I run the FindTableItems function it resets the rows/number to the appropriate size, but does not put any data into the cells.

I can see that the objects are holding the correct data. I recieve no compile errors but the debugger makes the note:

QTableWidget: cannot insert an item that is already owned by another QTableWidget

What I don't understand is I only have one tablewidget ? so whats the deal ? I'm also open to a different way of doing this.

```
void MainWindow::FindTableItems(QString searchItem)
{
    QList<int> matches;

    QList<QList<QTableWidgetItem*> > allRows;

    QList<QTableWidgetItem*> tempRow;

    QList<QTableWidgetItem *> tempTable = ui->tableWidget->findItems(searchItem,Qt::MatchContains);
    foreach(QTableWidgetItem *rowPtr,tempTable)
    {
    int currentRow = rowPtr->row();
    matches.append(currentRow);
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < ui->tableWidget->rowCount(); ++i)
    {
        if(matches.contains(i))
        {

            QTableWidgetItem *tempCaseNameItem = new QTableWidgetItem;
            QTableWidgetItem *tempInterviewNameItem = new QTableWidgetItem;
            QTableWidgetItem *tempInterviewerNameItem = new QTableWidgetItem;
            QTableWidgetItem *tempIntervieweeNameItem = new QTableWidgetItem;
            QTableWidgetItem *tempObserverNameItem = new QTableWidgetItem;
            QTableWidgetItem *tempDateItem = new QTableWidgetItem;

            tempCaseNameItem->setText(ui->tableWidget->item(i,0)->text());
            tempRow.append(tempCaseNameItem);

            tempInterviewNameItem->setText(ui->tableWidget->item(i,1)->text());
            tempRow.append(tempInterviewNameItem);

            tempInterviewerNameItem->setText(ui->tableWidget->item(i,2)->text());
            tempRow.append(tempInterviewerNameItem);

            tempIntervieweeNameItem->setText(ui->tableWidget->item(i,3)->text());
            tempRow.append(tempIntervieweeNameItem);

            tempObserverNameItem->setText(ui->tableWidget->item(i,4)->text());
            tempRow.append(tempObserverNameItem);

            tempDateItem->setText(ui->tableWidget->item(i,5)->text());
            tempRow.append(tempDateItem);

            allRows.append(tempRow);
        }
    }
    ui->tableWidget->setRowCount(0);
    foreach(QList<QTableWidgetItem*> rowItems, allRows)
    {
        int row = ui->tableWidget->rowCount();
        ui->tableWidget->insertRow(row);

        foreach(QTableWidgetItem *rowItem, rowItems)
        {
            for(int i = 0; i < 6; ++i)
            {
                ui->tableWidget->setItem(row, i, rowItem);
               // ui->tableWidget->item(row, i)->setTextAlignment(Qt::AlignVCenter);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a bad for loop, at the bottom, sorry's should have paid more attention